# How to integrate Framework 7 with shadow-cljs and clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript, html-framework-7, shadow-cljs

When I try to initialize Framework7 and Framework7-React within a clojurescript project, using shadow-cljs I get errors like this:

```
f7.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Framework7 is not a constructor
   at Object.init (f7.js:31)
   at F7App.value (app.js:162)
   at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:21965)
   at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:363)
   at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (react-dom.development.js:412)
   at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:467)
   at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:25025)
   at exports.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:816)
   at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:12189)
   at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:24866)
```

The Framework7 initialization normally consists of nothing more than the following

```
// Import Framework7
import Framework7 from 'framework7/framework7-lite.esm.bundle.js';

// Import Framework7-React Plugin
import Framework7React from 'framework7-react';

// Import Framework7 Styles
import 'framework7/css/framework7.bundle.css';

// Init F7 React Plugin
Framework7.use(Framework7React);
```

There is a hacky solution, the involves two separate build pipelines in order to get
Framework7 up and running in a simple shadow-cljs sample project.

I created a [a test project](https://github.com/bastiion/fulcro-shadow-cljs-framework7) that shows both versions, the non-working clojurescript version, where the error occurs can be run by:

```
npx shadow-cljs watch :direct-no-webpack
```

It uses the  `client2.cljs`

The working version initializes Framework7 using the ES6 import syntax, and is transpiled using webpack.

```
yarn run build-dev
npx shadow-cljs watch :direct
```

It produces the above mentioned error.

I do not understand in detail, what exactly is going on in Framework7 as multiple wrappers are involved.

How can I correctly import and use Framework7  with Clojurescript and Shadow-CLJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I read the shadow-clj  [guidelines on how to use npm packages](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_using_npm_packages). I had to use the direct path to the Javascript-files in the `node_modules` directory.

The correct imports are:

```
(ns app.ui.client2
  (:require
     ["framework7/framework7-lite.esm.bundle.js" :default Framework7]
     ["framework7-react/framework7-react.esm.js" :default Framework7React]))
```

I modifed the test project mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Framework7 but it is usually best to just follow the most basic instructions. In this case I added no additional build config and just required the packages directly.

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:require
     ["framework7" :as f7]
     ["framework7-react" :as f7r]))

;; avoiding top-level side-effects because of hot-reload
(defn init []
   (.use f7 f7r))
```

I can't tell if this actually works but it didn't throw an error. Avoid accessing ".esm.js" files or so directly since may cause conflicts if you access those but "framework7-react" accesses different ones. Mixing CommonJS and ESM files is not well supported at the moment.

`.css` imports are not supported by `shadow-cljs`.

Comment: thanks a lot. It indeed had to do with the imports. I modified the test project for reference.

Comment: I strongly advise against manually reaching into packages like that.You will still end up "mixing" ESM/CommonJS this way and it might get you in trouble. It is an unsolved problem and likely why webpack5 is taking so long. I suspect there will be a lot of breaking changes in this area in the future.

Comment: I agree. Personally, I always get confused with all the different import flavours. As long as no one proposes a better way to do it, I have to stick with my solution, as this is the only working solution right now. Yours throws exactly the same runtime-error as posted.